# Unable to initialise appium driver

Tags: android, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

I am unable to initialize appium driver. Please help.

I am getting below error message while initializing it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory.createDefault()Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/http/HttpClient$Factory;
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.<init>(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:93)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:93)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:95)
    at com.xceedance.framework.Hybrid.AppiumWebsite.main(AppiumWebsite.java:53)
```

I used the below code-

```
 AppiumDriver driver;
 DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();

 capability.setCapability("deviceName","emulator-5554");

 capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
 capability.setCapability("browserName","Chrome");

 capability.setCapability("platformName","Android");

 capability.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "7.1.1");

 capability.setCapability("appPackage","com.android.chrome");

 capability.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");

  driver=new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capability);
```

Comment: Did you added the required jars files in your project? You must have **java-client** and **selenium-java** library in your project. I suggest you to use maven project and  add all the required dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Looks like appium/selenium compatibility issue. look for the latest version and try.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating session incorrectly, you can read [Appium official docs](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/mobile-web/) for web testing setup.

First, make sure:

- Chrome is installed on your device or emulator.
- Chromedriver is installed and compatible with Chrome version on your device. [Check here](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver/index.html)

Create session following way:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "7.1.1");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "emulator-5554");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
AppiumDriver  driver=new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capability);
```

If you will get an error like:

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
Original error: unknown error: Chrome version must be >= 55.0.2883.0
```

Then re-install appium with the proper version of chromedriver:

```
npm install appium --chromedriver_version="your_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;



    File fs = new File("src");  //Assume your aap is inside src folder.
    File appPath = new File(fs, "YourAppAPK.apk");

    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "RealDeviceNameOrEmulatorName");
    caps.setCapability("app",appPath.getAbsolutePath());
    caps.setCapability("automationName","uiautomator2");
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "android");
    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // Test Actions Here
     System.out.println("Android Driver Started: "+driver);
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that you most likely have compiled a class against a different version of the class that is missing a method, than the one you are using when running it.

It is clearly mentioned in stack trace that method is not exist. If the exception appears when calling a method on an object in a library, you are most likely using separate versions of the library when compiling and running. Make sure you have the right version both places.

So it’s compatibility issue and HttpClient.Factory class belongs to **selenium** Library so Please check with selenium version is compatible or not